# amchart - Multiple Y-axis using the same X-axis

Tags: java, javascript, scala, playframework, amcharts

I'm puzzled...

I'm trying to create a serial amchart with multiple Y-axis, but I would like them to use the same X-axis. Amcharts.com has a demo (http://www.amcharts.com/demos/multiple-value-axes/)

I've put my output on JSfiddle for you to see: http://jsfiddle.net/2cMMF/3/
As you can see the the years are displayed twice on the X-axis,

This script I have copied, but I can seem to get it right. The only thing that is different is the chartData:

```
  function generateChartData() {
            var chartData = [];
            var xAxis;
            var yAxis;

            @for(j <- 0 until totalAmountForms){
                @for(i <- 0 until data.get(j).length) {
                yAxis = @data.get(j).get(i)
                xAxis = @label.get(j).get(i)
                @if(j==0){
                    chartData.push({
                        values1: yAxis,
                        categories: xAxis
                });
                }
                @if(j==1){
                    chartData.push({
                        values2: yAxis,
                        categories: xAxis
                });
                }
                @if(j==2){
                    chartData.push({
                        values3: yAxis,
                        categories: xAxis
                });
                }
                @if(j==3){
                    chartData.push({
                        values4: yAxis,
                        categories: xAxis
                });
                }
                @if(j==4){
                    chartData.push({
                        values5: yAxis,
                        categories: xAxis
                });
                }
            }
            }
            return chartData;  
            }
```

Any idea on what I might been doing wrong here?
I've also tried to generate the xAxis once, but just get "undefined" in the graph X-axis.
Here is where I give the xAxis to the graph:

```
"categoryField":"categories",
                "categoryAxis": {
                "parseDate": false,
                "axisColor": "#DADADA",
                "minorGridEnabled": true
            }
```

I'm using the Play Framework together with Scala (the code is valid, and compiles, but is not showing the graphs right).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey, guys!

The answer was to simply push the "values" to chartData together with "categories".
See example below:

```
function generateChartData() {
            var chartData = [];
            var xAxis;
            var yAxis1;
            var yAxis2;
            var yAxis3;
            var yAxis4;
            var yAxis5;

                @if(totalAmountForms==1){
                    @for(i <- 0 until data.get(0).length) {
                        xAxis = @label.get(0).get(i)
                        yAxis1 = @data.get(0).get(i)

                    chartData.push({
                        values1: yAxis1,
                        categories: xAxis
                });
                    }
                }
                @if(totalAmountForms==2){
                    @for(i <- 0 until data.get(1).length) {
                        xAxis = @label.get(0).get(i)
                        yAxis1 = @data.get(0).get(i)
                        yAxis2 = @data.get(1).get(i)

                    chartData.push({
                        values1: yAxis1,
                        values2: yAxis2,
                        categories: xAxis
                });
                    }
                }
                @if(totalAmountForms==3){
                    @for(i <- 0 until data.get(2).length) {
                        xAxis = @label.get(0).get(i)
                        yAxis1 = @data.get(0).get(i)
                        yAxis2 = @data.get(1).get(i)
                        yAxis3 = @data.get(2).get(i)

                    chartData.push({
                        values1: yAxis1,
                        values2: yAxis2,
                        values3: yAxis3,
                        categories: xAxis
                });
                    }
                }
                @if(totalAmountForms==4){
                    @for(i <- 0 until data.get(3).length) {
                        xAxis = @label.get(0).get(i)
                        yAxis1 = @data.get(0).get(i)
                        yAxis2 = @data.get(1).get(i)
                        yAxis3 = @data.get(2).get(i)
                        yAxis4 = @data.get(3).get(i)

                    chartData.push({
                        values1: yAxis1,
                        values2: yAxis2,
                        values3: yAxis3,
                        values4: yAxis4,
                        categories: xAxis
                });
                    }
                }
                @if(totalAmountForms==5){
                    @for(i <- 0 until data.get(4).length) {
                        xAxis = @label.get(0).get(i)
                        yAxis1 = @data.get(0).get(i)
                        yAxis2 = @data.get(1).get(i)
                        yAxis3 = @data.get(2).get(i)
                        yAxis4 = @data.get(3).get(i)
                        yAxis5 = @data.get(4).get(i)

                    chartData.push({
                        values1: yAxis1,
                        values2: yAxis2,
                        values3: yAxis3,
                        values4: yAxis4,
                        values5: yAxis5,
                        categories: xAxis
                });
                    }
                }
            return chartData;  
            }
```

Not the best code I've written, but it works for now...